# Save password securely in database in .NET Core 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API with C#. Currently a function in my controller takes a plain text password submitted by the user along with other information and saves it into a `Users` table.

How can I save the password securely instead of plain text? I am looking for a simple but secure solution. Are there any functions which simply generate a unique password hash which I can then save to the database?

For example :

```
user.Password = hash(request.password);
```

I have search older similar questions but as all the answers seem several years old I felt it may be worth while seeking out more current thoughts on this.

Comment: API clients should not be passing passwords, and you should not be storing the secrets they exchange yourself anyway. Look into existing identity servers, don't reinvent the authentication wheel. If you must, you can use (parts of) ASP.NET Identity for password hashing.

Comment: It's for user registration, therefore I would need to send the username and password to register to the API, which should store it securely in the database

Comment: This is a broad question. Anyway,  worth reading: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html. Only a hash is really not suitable anymore

Answer (score 2):

> It's for user registration, therefore I would need to send the username and password to register to the API, which should store it securely in the database

In that case, use [ASP.NET Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio). It provides you with user tables in your database, and a C# API to create and log in users.

Then to let users register using an API call: create a controller that accepts a registration request along with the appropriate model, and call `UserManager.CreateAsync(model.Email, model.Password)`.

Make sure to rate limit and monitor the endpoint to prevent abuse, as you won't have XHR or CAPTHCHA capabilities like a browser UI can have.

Comment: I had a look at IPasswordHasher but agree that looking at the whole ASP.NET Identity approach would be a better option.  Thanks for your guidance